# get range from google sheets using r1c1

Tags: google-apps-script, range, google-sheets-api

I want to get range selected from r1c1 r2c2

I have

```
var rc1 = '0:0-3:3';
//considering the string
var res = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('R0C0:R3C3');
ss.getActiveSheet().setActiveSelection(res);
```

I get error Range not found

Comment: Why don't you use the A1 notation ?

Comment: its a reverse engineered product and it affects entire structure. Please help

Comment: Hi @Code Guy. Did you make some progress on your problem ? Are you still blocked ?

Answer (score 1):

Your range is not found cause you trying to get element out of the table. R0C0 does not exist, R1C1 is the first existing element.

If you want to get range selected from R1C1 to R2C2, you've got

```
function getWithRCNotation(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var res = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('R1C1:R2C2');
  ss.getActiveSheet().setActiveSelection(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you follow the instructions in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function). Based from this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/yee3S5UI3Pw), when you pass a range, a1:d12 for example, to a function in gSheets, the values of the cells in that range are passed as an array. Try to pass it as a string, like `=function("a1:d12")`, and deal with the string notation for a range, `...getRange(stringargument)`.